# How to trigger pop up modal via another modal button if the php logic is met?

Tags: javascript, php, popup, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

i am new to php and bootstrap modals

I'm trying to create a login form that will automatically send an otp and open the verify otp pop up modal, unfortunately the modal and the php function is not working.

This is the code

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbName = "votesystem";

$data = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbName);
    if (!$data) {
        die("Connection error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

session_start();
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST" && isset($_POST["phone"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM voters WHERE phone = ? AND password = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($data, $sql);
if (!$stmt) {
  die("Could not prepare statement: " . mysqli_error($data));
}

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $phone, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $_SESSION['user_authenticated'] = true;
    require_once 'send_otp.php'; 

    $otp = rand(1000, 9999);
    $otp_expiry = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+5 minutes'));
    $_SESSION["otp"] = $otp;

    sendOTP($phone, $otp);

    echo '<script>$("#otpVerificationModal").modal("show");</script>';
} else {
    echo "Incorrect phone or password. Please try again.";
}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
?>


<div class="top-container">
    <div class="info-box">
        <p class="header">
            Experience the easiest, friendly user, secure voting system!
        </p>
        <p class="info-text">
        </p>
    </div>
  
  <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">Please Enter Credentials</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="#" method="POST" id="loginForm">
          <div class="form-element">
                    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                    <input type="number" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Registered No.">
          </div>
          <div class="form-element">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
            </form>
      </div>
       
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="loginForm" name="btn">Sign in</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="info-buttons">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop" id="nav-btn">
       VOTE!
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="otpVerificationModal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="otpVerificationModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="otpVerificationModalLabel">Verify OTP</h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="verify_otp.php" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-element">
                        <label for="otp">Enter OTP</label>
                        <input type="number" id="otp" name="otp" placeholder="Enter OTP">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Verify OTP</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
  function openOTPModal() {
    $("#otpVerificationModal").modal("show");
  }

  if (<?php echo isset($_SESSION['user_authenticated']) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>) {
    openOTPModal();
  }
});

</script>
```

it always go to localhost/test/# even if the password and phone is incorrect, is there any way to handle it?

Comment: What are you expecting it to do if the password or phone are incorrect?

Comment: show a notification saying password and phone are incorrect, if its correct send an otp to the phone number and open the 2nd modal which is the verify OTP

Comment: _"it always go to localhost/test/# even if the password and phone is incorrect"_ - of course it goes there - your login form has `action="#"`, so if you were on `/test/` already, that is naturally the resulting URL, when you submit that form. But that has happened _before_ you even checked the credentials - so there really is no point here in stating this like you did, as if it had anything to do with the problem.